# Updating Lettuce Connection Factory Dynamically

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, lettuce

We are using Spring Data Redis and AWS Elastic cache in a clustered mode.

We are using the AWS Elastic Cache cluster URL to connect to Redis.

We are configuring the LettuceConnectionFactory like this . We are using TopologyRefreshOptions to take care of the failover and slot movement scenarios.

```
ClusterClientOptions clusterClientOptions = ClusterClientOptions.builder()
                //.timeoutOptions(TimeoutOptions.enabled(Duration.ofSeconds(60L)))
                .topologyRefreshOptions(ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions.builder()
                        .enablePeriodicRefresh(Duration.ofSeconds(10L)) 
                        .enableAllAdaptiveRefreshTriggers() 
                        .dynamicRefreshSources(false)
                        .build())
                .autoReconnect(true)
                .cancelCommandsOnReconnectFailure(true)
                .disconnectedBehavior(ClientOptions.DisconnectedBehavior.REJECT_COMMANDS)
                .build();
        LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = LettucePoolingClientConfiguration.builder()
                .clientOptions(clusterClientOptions)
                .build();
        RedisClusterConfiguration redisClusterConfiguration = new RedisClusterConfiguration();
        redisClusterConfiguration.addClusterNode(new RedisNode(redisHost, redisPort));
        redisClusterConfiguration.setPassword(redisPassword);
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisClusterConfiguration, clientConfig);
```

With this configuration also we are facing "moved" issues which typically comes from the hash slot movement across the nodes.
Sometimes after the restart of the app , the app starts working fine.

i was thinking if we can proactively update the LettuceConnectionFactory by updating the CLusterNodes on the LettuceClientConfiguration on receiving the Moved exception ?

Best Regards,

Saurav